# NoMethodError - undefined method `borrower_individuals' for #<Individual::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x000000000dc58660>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't work out why this is not working

**Models**

```
class CompanyBorrower < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :borrower_individuals
    has_many :individuals, -> { distinct }, :through => :borrower_individuals
end

class BorrowerIndividual < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :company_borrower, optional: true
    belongs_to :individual, optional: true
end

class Individual < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :borrower_individuals
    has_many :company_borrowers, :through => :borrower_individuals
end
```

**Controller**

```
@borrower = CompanyBorrower.find(params[:id])
@individuals = @borrower.individuals.all
@roles = @individuals.borrower_individuals.all
```

**And I get the error...**

```
undefined method `borrower_individuals' for #<Individual::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x000000000dc58660>
```

The error is happening on @roles - if I remove, the error disappears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@borrower = CompanyBorrower.find(params[:id])
@individuals = @borrower.individuals.all
@roles = @individuals.borrower_individuals.all
```

Here You are calling the association method on **ActiveRecordRelation object** not on **Active Record object**.i.e You are calling it on colletion of ActiveRecords not on single record.You need to call association method on single record.
     @individuals = @borrower.individuals.all

Here you have called individulas(association method) on single active record object(@borrower).It will return colletion of ActiveRecords (ActiveRecord_Relation object) if records are present(if records are not present , it will return empty active record relation object). In the next line you are trying to call the
borrower_individuals(association method) on the rective record relation object.That's why it throws error

```
@roles = @individuals.borrower_individuals.all
```

you need to rewrite above code

```
@roles = @individuals.map(&:borrower_individuals).flatten
```

As Marek Lipka mentioned , it will cause N+1 query and return the array object.
In order to avoid N+1 query, we can change it

```
@borrower = CompanyBorrower.find(params[:id])
@individuals = @borrower.individuals.all
@roles = @individuals.borrower_individuals.all

@borrower = CompanyBorrower.includes(individuals: [:borrower_individuals]).find(params[:id])
@individuals = @borrower.individuals.all
@roles = @individuals.map(&:borrower_individuals).flatten # will return array object.
```

you can avoid @individuals and @roles variable if you are going to use it in html page.It depends on how you are going to use it

Comment: `@roles = @individuals.map(&:borrower_individuals).flatten` will cause N + 1 unless you change the line that sets `@individuals`. Plus, with this approach, `@roles` is not relation - it's usually better to hold "bunch of `ActiveRecord` objects" as relation instead of array, for a couple of reasons.

Comment: Sorry I forgot  to mention the use of includes while finding CompanyBorrower object

Answer (score 2):

`@individual` doesn't hold single `Individual` instance, it contains `Relation` instead, on which you can't call `Individual` instance methods, obviously. You can set your `@roles` in a little bit different way, for example:

```
@roles = BorrowerIndividual.where(individual_id: @individuals.pluck(:id))
```

But to be honest, I don't know if it's necessary in your situation, because it seems to me you try to solve rather simple problem in a little bit overcomplicated way.